# Shower Valve Shutoff Screws

Tags: shower

[image]

Pictured here is what I thought was a shower valve shutoff screw.  There is another one on the other side of the valve.  I turned the screws clockwise to tighten and shut off the water so I could replace the cartridge; however, they just kept turning without tightening.  Are these not shower valve shutoff screws?  Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the valve's make/model? Hopefully the manufacturer has some info on exactly what parts are where, and how to use them

Answer (score 8):

Try turning the slots so they are vertical to turn off the water to the cartridge. That's how mine work. Then turn the slots horizontal to turn water back on.

Comment: In other words, those service stops are "ball valves" or something similar, and do not tighten.